# Git alias for searching for commit messages

Tags: git, search, alias, message, commit

I do have aliases found on the web:

```
find = "log --decorate -i --all --date=short --grep"

search = "!f() { git log --decorate --grep=$1 -i --all --date=short; }; f"
```

They both do the same: search within commit messages.  Is there one somehow one "superior" to the other?  Why?

QUESTION -- How could we write an alias for searching for commits that contain particular words in the message?

For example, where:

```
git search-msg foo bar baz
```

would **match commits containing the words `foo`, `bar` and `baz`**, in whichever order?

ANSWER -- Better formatting here (from LeGEC):

```
search-msg = "!f() { str=\"git log --all-match\"; \
                     for var in \"$@\"; do \
                         str=\"$str --grep '$var'\"; \
                     done; \
                     eval $str; }; f"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a word about git log's [`--grep` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grepltpatterngt) :

- you can specify it multiple times
- default multiple grep is "match any of the patterns"
- there is an additional [`--all-match` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---all-match), which indicates "match *all* of the patterns"

Example :

```
# two commits contain 'foo' in their message (one of them also contains 'bar'):
$ git log --oneline --grep foo
b76121c bar baz foo
b7a342f foo

# two commits contain 'bar' in their message (one of them also contains 'foo'):
$ git log --oneline --grep bar
bbb27f3 (HEAD -> master) bar
b76121c bar baz foo

# if I look for both patterns : I get the union of both searches (3 commits)
$ git log --oneline --grep foo --grep bar
bbb27f3 (HEAD -> master) bar
b76121c bar baz foo
b7a342f foo

# if I add '--all-match' : only the commit which contains both is kept
$ git log --oneline --grep foo --grep bar --all-match
b76121c bar baz foo
```

---

To answer your question : here is a sample script that takes a list of arguments, and turns them into a `git log --all-match --grep aaa --grep bbb` command :

```
# in file git-search-msg :

#!/bin/bash

cmd=("log" "--all-match")

for var in "$@"
do
        cmd+=('--grep')
        cmd+=("$var")
done

git "${cmd[@]}"
```

If you paste this in a file named `git-search-msg`, and put it somewhere on your `PATH`, then `git search-msg foo bar baz` will do what you want.

---

The following works in plain `sh`, but uses `eval` :

```
#!/bin/sh
str="git log --all-match"

for var in "$@"
do
    # This loops takes arguments one by one and adds
    # them as '--grep' args to the 'git log' command.
    str="$str --grep '$var'"
done

# tech note : this sample script does not escape single quotes
eval $str
```

If you manage to oneline it (and escape it correctly), you can use it in an alias.

Beware the escaping problems mixed with `eval` though ...

Comment: As a script, it does work well (though it's not case-insensitive, but that's a param to add).

Comment: Now, is it convertible to a git alias?  I tried the `!f() { …}; f` schema, but with no success...

Comment: The `cmd` array of arguments is `bash` syntax, AFAIK git aliases are interpreted with `sh`, and there are no arrays in `sh`. One way would be to build a string with the arguments and execute it (`eval` or `sh -c`), be careful about escaping though.

Comment: What kind of limitations do you have with the script version ?

Comment: The thing is I need to have everything in one file, `.gitconfig`, that's shared among coworkers.

Comment: I added an `sh` version ; do ponder the other solution of sharing (and installing) the script, though

Comment: thanks a lot. I learned with your answers!  And it does work perfectly...

Comment: For you, is there a diff between the `find` and the `search` alias above, in my post?  Anyone better than the other?

Comment: as they are currently written : the `find` alias allows you to add other options, e.g : `git find foo --first-parent --onleline -- in/this/dir`. Since you only add options to one single git command, I see no benefit to the function wrapper.

Comment: Thanks a lot, interesting comment indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add history to search through the whole repository, by adding `rev-list` to your `git log`

```
git log --grep 'Something relevant in my commits' $(git rev-list --all)
```

Something like should work in the **.gitconfig** file

```
[alias]
    search = "!f() { git log --grep \"$1\" $(git rev-list --all); }; f"
[log]
    date = iso
```

The `date = iso` thing is here to get a better date (current format is `2019-11-26 17:35:30 +0100`)

Comment: Dear @Ben, Thanks for trying, but that does not solve the question of just displaying commits which do have "foo" and "bar" and "baz" in whichever order in their subject line, when called as `git search foo bar baz`.

Comment: It evens seems to duplicate message lines, though with a different commit id... Would it be things merged or rebased, from the history?

Comment: That's the alias I am currently using and it didn't show any duplicates. 

It parse every commits to search an occurence in commit message, so I guess merge commits should be returned too, because they are commits and they are containing the message you are looking for

Comment: I'll try to show you / understand why there are duplicates (same author, same commit message, same date and time, but different hash).

Comment: Wanna try to answer the question, for having an alias permitting to find commit messages containing string1 and string2 and … and stringN?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, using git commands with anonymous bash functions gives us access to additional goodies.

Here's the output of a search alias i made that does what you want. I created 4 commits with the commit messages "1", "2", "3", "4":

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test (new)
$ git ls -4
d0ebbb3 (HEAD -> new) 4 [Martin Kjeldsen]
174f539 3 [Martin Kjeldsen]
43d6a01 2 [Martin Kjeldsen]
05e7e0a 1 [Martin Kjeldsen]

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test (new)
$ git search 1 2 3 4
commit 05e7e0a232e093ddfcbd90d8071dc4a84e4295b7
Author: Martin Kjeldsen <kjeldsen@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 15 23:09:02 2019 +0100

    1
commit 43d6a019742a38c1b06aa7a40bc8f34d46d0dcc8
Author: Martin Kjeldsen <kjeldsen@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 29 00:57:38 2019 +0100

    2
commit 174f539b151533406b5fa7f2c8541dfeb194bfac
Author: Martin Kjeldsen <kjeldsen@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 29 00:57:46 2019 +0100

    3
commit d0ebbb3eb1071653b0578cfdd14c0d6a7c112b1f
Author: Martin Kjeldsen <kjeldsen@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 29 00:58:01 2019 +0100

    4
```

Another test:

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/test (new)
$ git search 2 4
commit 43d6a019742a38c1b06aa7a40bc8f34d46d0dcc8
Author: Martin Kjeldsen <kjeldsen@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 29 00:57:38 2019 +0100

    2
commit d0ebbb3eb1071653b0578cfdd14c0d6a7c112b1f
Author: Martin Kjeldsen <kjeldsen@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 29 00:58:01 2019 +0100

    4
```

Here's the alias which simply loops over each argument and calls `git log --grep`. Equivalent of calling `git log --grep <a> --grep <b> --grep <c> ...`:

```
[alias]    
search = "!f() { for l in \"$@\"; do git log --grep \"$l\"; done; }; f"
```

Comment: thanks, almost there - with one exception: here, it returns all commits with a or b or c. While the question is over getting all commits with a and b and c.